# split comma separated string in c# and needs to save it in two separate variables

Tags: c#

I have to split the comma - separated string in c# and needs to save it in two variables. The C# function is as follows :

```
public int InsertLogDetails(string RunIDStartTime, int Distribution_ID, List<string> additions, List<string> removals, bool status, string ErrorMessage)
{
    int Run_ID=0;
    DateTime StartTime=DateTime.Now;
    //Needs to split RunIDStartTime and needs to save it in Run_ID and StartTime
}
```

The RunIDStartTime holds the value of Run_ID ans StartTime.(Eg: 5,Jan 23 2013  9:31AM)

Anybody please helpout. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to save the date and month?

Comment: Your tile does not support the code you have provided ..where is the so called comma separated string..?

Comment: Try the split command on `RunIDStartTime`.

Comment: @Shoban : 5,Jan 23 2013 9:31AM..Here 5 indicates Run ID and Jan 23 2013 9:31AM indicates StartTime

Comment: @DJKRAZE : 5,Jan 23 2013 9:31AM..Here 5 indicates Run ID and Jan 23 2013 9:31AM indicates StartTime

Comment: prabu R I figured it out what you were talking about 15 mins ago.. was just wanting to make sure.. so I provided you an answer based on your example that would work there are many good working examples provided by others as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working answer and you do not need to do .ToArray because Split already returns an array.

```
var RunIDStartTime = "5,Jan 23 2013 9:31AM";
var listSplit = RunIDStartTime.Split(','); 
var id = int.Parse(listSplit[0]);
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(listSplit[1]);
```

`returns id = 5 and date = Jan 23 2013 9:31AM`

Answer (score 1):

Use `int.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParseExact` with DateFormat to parse the string. To Split, using `string.Split`, Something like:

```
string RunIDStartTime = "5,Jan 23 2013 9:31AM";

int Run_ID = 0;
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.MinValue;
string[] splittedArray = RunIDStartTime.Split(',');
if (splittedArray.Length >= 2)
{
    if (int.TryParse(splittedArray[0], out Run_ID))
    {
        //valid ID
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid ID
    }
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(splittedArray[1],"MMM d yyyy h:mmtt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out StartTime))
    {
        //Valid date
    }
    else
    {
        //invalid date
    }
}
```

For output:

```
Console.WriteLine("ID : {0} Date: {1}", Run_ID, StartTime.ToString());
```

Output:

```
ID : 5 Date: 23/01/2013 9:31:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int InsertLogDetails(string RunIDStartTime, int Distribution_ID, List<string> additions, List<string> removals, bool status, string ErrorMessage)
{

    var tokens = RunIDStartTime.split(',');
    int Run_ID= int.Parse(tokens[0]);
    DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Parse(tokens[1],"MMM d yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);        
}
```